# Chance of selecting a duplicate?

Tags: probability, statistics

When you select things at random repeatedly (with replacement or whatever) out of a field of N possible things, how do you calculate the probability that something has been chosen X times after Y choices were made? For example, if there are 64 DotA 2 heroes and I choose a random one 9 times, what's the chance that I get Skeleton King 5 of those times?

Comment: At least 5 or exactly 5?

Comment: Both, I guess..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the probability of getting $k$ successes in $n$ [Bernoulli trials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial). If exactly five, you multiply:

- the probability of, in a game, getting Skeleton King ($1/64$); done five times
- the probability of, in a game,  not Skeleton King ($63/64$); done four times
- the number of distinct rearrangements of these 9 events, which is ${{9}\choose{5}}$ – intuitively, this is the number of ways to "choose" the 5 games out of 9 where you rolled Skeleton King.

Rolling this all up, the formula is ([Wolfram Alpha link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%289%20choose%204%29%20%281/64%29%5E5%20%2863/64%29%5E4)):

$${{9}\choose{5}} \left(\frac{1}{64}\right)^5\left(\frac{63}{64}\right)^4 \approx 1.1 \times 10^{-7}.$$

For the probability that you rolled Skeleton King at least five times, you can use the same formula but sum up all the possibilities past 5 up through 9 ([Wolfram Alpha link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28%20combination%289,k%29%20%281/64%29%5Ek%20%2863/64%29%5E%289-k%29%20,k,5,9%29)):

$$ \sum_{k=5}^9 {{9}\choose{k}}\left(\frac{1}{64}\right)^k \left(\frac{63}{64}\right)^{9-k} \approx 1.1 \times 10^{-7}.$$

So the answer is: about 1 in 9 million.

Comment: Your explanation of why ${9 \choose 5}$ occurs is a little incomplete. The 5 things you're choosing are the 5 slots out of 9 where Skeleton King occurs. Also, shouldn't the resulting number be less than $1$?

Comment: Both points are true. Will edit to reflect that.